# Sharing BJT bias resistors

Tags: amplifier, rf, analog, bjt, radio

I am designing a radio and realize that I have many of the same BJT circuit blocks that are biased with the same resistor values.

Can I simplify construction by having a "bias line" that I can just connect my transistor bases to? Note: all emitter resistors are also the same.

I ask because LTspice seems to have no issues with it, but I have never seen it in any RF schematic.

[image: From This]

[image: To This]

Comment: Nope.  Each stage has to be independant if you want each stage to work as an amplifier.  If it was possible, someone would of figured it out.

Comment: In your LTspice simulations, perform an FFT on the shared base node.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I guess it seemed to good to be true

Comment: @periblepsis Great point, learned something new today.

Comment: @YousifAlniemi I was struggling to write words and just decided that it would be easier to just see the result. ;)

Comment: This is fairly common in the common base topology, but does not easily work in the common emitter or emitter follower topologies as there the signal voltage is applied to the base.

Comment: @DanMills Interesting! I suppose that makes sense. An LTspice sim still shows a lot of noise and mixing on the biasing line though, I wonder how that is mitigated in practice

Comment: For example, R1 and R2 are in combination equivalent to a 24k resistor connected to a 1.25V voltage source, so that is a voltage source, and one resistor instead of two. If you use  the same bias voltage a lot this might save parts. I am not sure if there are practical issues.

Comment: @user253751  If all you were doing was biasing, but the ac inputs are different, which means biasing must be separate if you want amplification.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat no, this is a theorem that 100k to +5V + 33k to ground = 24k to 1.25V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would probably have some common mode currents when each amplifier sinks more current or when the input changes. The other problem is you would have to adjust the resistor divider to allow more current as the load current of each stage will drop the resistor divider voltage slightly. It's probably not worth dealing with these problems over the cost of saving a few cents.

Comment: Good points, seems like everything would operate sub-par. Not worth the hassle of more soldering.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but maybe; and, you merely drew it incorrectly.

Make a common rail, and run a bias resistor to each BJT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVbwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "maybe" is: if the stages shall be coupled to each other, notice that the bias network needs to be well enough filtered/bypassed (C1, maybe additional RC or LC sections) that you avoid creating a phase-shift oscillator between stages.  Or if they are amplifiers in separate signal paths where you need some maximum crosstalk between them, etc.

Notice this motif is mandatory for certain functions, like AGC in a traditional superhet design.  It might also be handy say when a multi-stage amplifier needs temperature compensation, where a common temperature reference can be used to bias multiple amplifier stages (which aren't necessarily matched, but could track well enough to use this method).

For general purposes, it's often not worth the bother, and the locality of bias resistors to each stage is worth putting in a few extras overall.

From a theoretical perspective, notice each bias connection (R3 + C2, etc.) constitutes a bias tee.  At low frequencies, this can be done with resistors (RC coupling), but at high frequencies an inductor may be better (LC coupling).

Further note that an amplifier like this, is basically a transistor and two bias tees.  It is then very well defined where the RF ports are (a port being a signal with respect to a well-defined reference, usually a common ground plane), and measurement is easy at those points specifically.

In an integrated design, we can combine input and output bias tees into a single R-C-R (or L-C-L or whatever) coupling network (or still more generally, an impedance-matching and filtering network), but it's worth noting the above, so that we are able to subdivide such a circuit and tune each stage by itself.

Comment: Interesting! Question though; if this is a case of fixed biasing with a single resistor, what would the voltage divider be for?

Comment: Fixed in what sense, or, to what?

Comment: Err sorry I guess that was a semantic error, I have seen using a single resistor connected to a voltage source to bias a BJT amplifier referred to as "fixed base" biasing; I figured if that was being done then why the voltage divider between VCC and the base resistor as opposed to VCC - resistor - base pin

Comment: Ah, well if you don't have some other voltage, a divider can still be used; notice the much smaller resistor values making the bias supply look like a voltage source in comparison to the base currents.